Italicizing a Lettrine on an Ad Hoc Basis
Consider the code:
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{lettrine,xcolor}

\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\color{red}{}} % for the initial argument.
\renewcommand{\LettrineTextFont}{\scshape} % for the second argument

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\lettrine[lines=1,loversize=.65,findent=-.08em,nindent=2.5pt]{A}{ regular} lettrine.

\vspace{25pt}

\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\color{red}\itshape} 
\renewcommand{\LettrineTextFont}{\itshape}
\lettrine[lines=1,loversize=.65,findent=.02em,nindent=2.5pt]{I}{talicized} lettrine. 

\vspace{25pt}

\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\color{red}{}} 
\renewcommand{\LettrineTextFont}{\scshape}
\lettrine[lines=1,loversize=.65,findent=-.08em,nindent=2.5pt]{B}{ack} to a regular lettrine.
\end{document}

which produces:

What I have done allows me to change from the defined lettrine to an italicized one; however, in an actual document, this may occur multiple times. I am thinking that there must be a better (more efficient) way to do this.
QUESTION: What is the preferable way to convert the defined lettrine to an italicized one which would circumvent the need to redefine the lettrine after the italicized one is used? I am compiling with lualatex
Thank you.

Guessing that really do you want   "talicized" in italics, but maintaining the small caps for document consistency:
\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage[lines=1,loversize=.65,findent=-.08em,nindent=2.5pt]{lettrine}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\parskip3em
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\color{red}{}} % for the initial argument.
\renewcommand{\LettrineTextFont}{\scshape} % for the second argument
\newcommand\Itttrine[2]{\lettrine{\em #1}{\em #2}}
\begin{document}

\lettrine{A}{regular} lettrine.
\Itttrine{I}{talicized} lettrine. 
\lettrine{B}{ack} to a regular lettrine.

\end{document}



Why \em and not \itshape?

It's shorter. Pure laziness. :)

You want to avoid resetting the parameters each time you want a lettrine, to begin with.
Next, you want your personal command to call \lettrine: there are several reasons to. For instance, you can define the command with a *-variant that chooses italic type, but not only.
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lmodern}% or other scalable font
\usepackage[lines=1,loversize=.65,findent=-.08em,nindent=2.5pt]{lettrine}

\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\color{red!80}} % for the initial argument.
\renewcommand{\LettrineTextFont}{\scshape} % for the second argument

\NewDocumentCommand{\orncap}{smm}{%
  \par\addvspace{25pt}
  \lettrine
   {\IfBooleanT{#1}{\itshape}#2}% <--- the drop capital
   {\IfBooleanT{#1}{\itshape}#3}% <--- the rest of the first word
}


\begin{document}

\orncap{A}{ regular} lettrine.

\orncap*{I}{talicized} lettrine.

\orncap{B}{ack} to a regular lettrine.

\end{document}


You see that I also incorporate a \par command with a suitable vertical spacing, so you have not to provide it explicitly.
A possible improvement would be to define \orncap also with an optional argument
\NewDocumentCommand{\orncap}{sO{}mm}{%
  \par\addvspace{25pt}
  \lettrine[#2]%
   {\IfBooleanT{#1}{\itshape}#3}% <--- the drop capital
   {\IfBooleanT{#1}{\itshape}#4}% <--- the rest of the first word
}

so you can pass options to \lettrine to fine tune in case of problematic letters.
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lmodern}% or other scalable font
\usepackage[lines=1,loversize=.65,findent=-.08em,nindent=2.5pt]{lettrine}

\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\color{red!80}} % for the initial argument.
\renewcommand{\LettrineTextFont}{\scshape} % for the second argument

\NewDocumentCommand{\orncap}{sO{}mm}{%
  \par\addvspace{25pt}
  \lettrine[#2]%
   {\IfBooleanT{#1}{\itshape}#3}% <--- the drop capital
   {\IfBooleanT{#1}{\itshape}#4}% <--- the rest of the first word
}

\begin{document}

\noindent text here

\orncap{A}{ regular} lettrine.

\orncap*{I}{talicized} lettrine. 

\orncap{B}{ack} to a regular lettrine.

\orncap*[lhang=0.15,findent=-0.4em]{W}{hether} I shall be the hero of my own life

\end{document}



Thank you for this answer egreg.
